# Push Notification Button not showing up in Microsoft App Center

Tags: notifications, push

I'd like to try the push notification feature of Microsoft App Center.

I'm logged in the app center portal. I created an app. When I click on the app, I see a bunch of buttons in the left pane (Diagnostics, Analysis, Settings) but there is no Push button like I normally see in tutorials, and videos.

Anyone know what I'm missing ? Is it a subscription issue ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue and got confused, since we have other apps that still 
have the 'Push' button on the left side. Upon further inspection i found [this notice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIrOl.png) on our existing apps. The notice links to [this url](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/appcenter/app-center-mbaas-retirement/)

Apparently they are shutting down push notification support on Appcenter and urges you to use [Azure Notification Hubs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/notification-hubs/) instead.

This kinda sucks, since we build multiple apps already with Appcenter push support, and they have not supplied us with a migration guide (yet)